# Qual a maneira mais fácil de classificar elementos DOM usando JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript

Como posso classificar elementos no DOM utilizando **JavaScript puro**, para ser mais claro, supomos que temos uma página de produtos estática, além dos produtos tem um campo para classificar os mesmos pelo preço.

```css
body {
    text-align: center
}
select {
    border: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
    padding: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}
.produtos {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
.produtos .item {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 24%;
}
.produtos .item:nth-child(4n+0) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.produtos .item h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.produtos .item h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Ordenar por:</option>
    <option value="maior_preco">Maior Preço</option>
    <option value="menor_preco">Menor Preço</option>
</select>

<div class="produtos clearfix">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
        <h2>Produto 04</h2>
        <h3>R$ 1.564,00</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
        <h2>Produto 07</h2>
        <h3>R$ 322,00</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
        <h2>Produto 01</h2>
        <h3>R$ 10,99</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
        <h2>Produto 03</h2>
        <h3>R$ 153,99</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
        <h2>Produto 06</h2>
        <h3>R$ 2,00</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
        <h2>Produto 08</h2>
        <h3>R$ 500,00</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
        <h2>Produto 05</h2>
        <h3>R$ 2.999,99</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
        <h2>Produto 02</h2>
        <h3>R$ 768,99</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que tem um array de produtos construído, que são os aparecem na página, pode utilizar a função [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) para aplicar uma ordenação por qualquer critério que pretenda. Esta função recebe uma função de comparação com as regras de comparação entre cada elemento.

Considerando produtos com a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
    imagem: string,
    nome: string,
    preco: double
}
```

Podemos ordenar do maior preço para o menor com:

```
produtos.sort(function(a,b){
  if (a.preco > b.preco) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if (b.preco > a.preco) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```

Lembrando que o `sort` recebe como parametro os 2 elementos a comparar, neste exemplo o `a` e o `b`, e devolve:

- `< 0` se o `a` for para ficar antes do `b`
- `> 0` se o `a` for para ficar depois do `b`
- `0` mantem os dois na ordem em que estão

Outra forma bem mais simplificada e compacta de obter o mesmo é:

```
produtos.sort((a,b) => b.preco - a.preco);
```

Que não só obtêm os retornos através da subtração assim como usa uma [*Arrow Function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) em vez de uma função normal. E para a ordenação do menor preço basta inverter a lógica da comparação:

```
produtos.sort((a,b) => a.preco - b.preco);
```

Veja o seu código a funcionar com este principio:

```js
let produtos = [
  {
    "imagem":"http://via.placeholder.com/300x150",
    "nome":"Produto 04",
    "preco":1564
  },
  {
    "imagem":"http://via.placeholder.com/300x150",
    "nome":"Produto 07",
    "preco":322
  },
  {
    "imagem":"http://via.placeholder.com/300x150",
    "nome":"Produto 01",
    "preco":10.99
  },
  {
    "imagem":"http://via.placeholder.com/300x150",
    "nome":"Produto 03",
    "preco":153.99
  },
  {
    "imagem":"http://via.placeholder.com/300x150",
    "nome":"Produto 06",
    "preco":2
  },
  {
    "imagem":"http://via.placeholder.com/300x150",
    "nome":"Produto 08",
    "preco":500
  },
  {
    "imagem":"http://via.placeholder.com/300x150",
    "nome":"Produto 05",
    "preco":2999.99
  },
  {
    "imagem":"http://via.placeholder.com/300x150",
    "nome":"Produto 02",
    "preco":768.99
  }
];

function mostrarProdutos(){
  let novoHtml = "";
  
  for (let i = 0; i < produtos.length; ++i){
    novoHtml += `<div class="item">
                    <img src="${produtos[i].imagem}" />
                    <h2>${produtos[i].nome}</h2>
                    <h3>${produtos[i].preco.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })}</h3>
                </div>`;
  }
  
  document.querySelector(".produtos").innerHTML = novoHtml;
}

const selectOrdenacao = document.querySelector("select");

selectOrdenacao.addEventListener("change", function(){
  if (selectOrdenacao.value == "maior_preco"){
    produtos.sort((a,b) => b.preco - a.preco);
  }
  else if (selectOrdenacao.value == "menor_preco"){
    produtos.sort((a,b) => a.preco - b.preco);
  }
  mostrarProdutos();
});

mostrarProdutos();
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center
}
select {
    border: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
    padding: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}
.produtos {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
.produtos .item {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 24%;
}
.produtos .item:nth-child(4n+0) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.produtos .item h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.produtos .item h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Ordenar por:</option>
    <option value="maior_preco">Maior Preço</option>
    <option value="menor_preco">Menor Preço</option>
</select>

<div class="produtos clearfix">
    
</div>
```

A função `mostrarProdutos` constrói o html todo que o `<div class="produtos clearfix">` tinha estaticamente com base no array de produtos e aplica-o através da propriedade `innerHTML`.

Assim no change do `<select>` resta apenas alterar a ordem dos elementos no array `produtos` com base no valor escolhido e voltar a chamar a função `mostrarProdutos`.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente `sort` é a maneira mais fácil, porém para aplicar direto ao `DOM`, sem alterar a estrutura, é necessário aplicar um expressão regular e formatar o valor para que possa ser tratado na função, exemplo...

```js
function ordenar() {

let op = document.getElementById("ord").value;
let itens = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
let itensNV = [];

function mpreco(a,b) {
     return parseFloat(a.preco.replace(/R\$|\.|\,|\s/g, "")) < parseFloat(b.preco.replace(/R\$|\.|\,|\s/g, "")) ? -1 : 1; }
               

function mapreco(a,b) {
     return parseInt(a.preco.replace(/R\$|\.|\,|\s/g, "")) > parseInt(b.preco.replace(/R\$|\.|\,|\s/g, "")) ? -1 : 1; }
              

for(let i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
 let content = {
  html : itens[i],
        preco : itens[i].children[2].textContent
 }
    itensNV.push(content);
}

switch(op) {
      case 'maior_preco':
   itensNV = itensNV.sort(mapreco);
      break;
      
      case 'menor_preco':
   itensNV = itensNV.sort(mpreco);
      break;
}

document.querySelector('.produtos').innerHTML = '';

for(let i = 0; i < itensNV.length; i++)
   document.querySelector('.produtos').appendChild(itensNV[i].html);

}
```

```css
    body {
        text-align: center
    }
    select {
        border: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif !important;
        padding: 4px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .clearfix {
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .produtos {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .produtos .item {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 1%;
        width: 24%;
    }
    .produtos .item:nth-child(4n+0) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .produtos .item h2 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .produtos .item h3 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
```

```html
<select onchange="ordenar()" id="ord">
        <option>Ordenar por:</option>
        <option value="maior_preco">Maior Preço</option>
        <option value="menor_preco">Menor Preço</option>
    </select>

    <div class="produtos clearfix">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
            <h2>Produto 04</h2>
            <h3>R$ 1.564,00</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
            <h2>Produto 07</h2>
            <h3>R$ 322,00</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
            <h2>Produto 01</h2>
            <h3>R$ 10,99</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
            <h2>Produto 03</h2>
            <h3>R$ 153,99</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
            <h2>Produto 06</h2>
            <h3>R$ 2,00</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
            <h2>Produto 08</h2>
            <h3>R$ 500,00</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
            <h2>Produto 05</h2>
            <h3>R$ 2.999,99</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
            <h2>Produto 02</h2>
            <h3>R$ 768,99</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```